# Bad redirect in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I've created a nodeJs project about a Todo-List
but I faced a problem with my delete anchor
I have a problem with my redirect it is not working
I have tried multiple ways but when I click it,
it still sends me to the id URL, which is not what I want.

my ejs code

```
`    <button class="Clear" data-doc="<% lists._id %>">Clear List</button>
  
    <div class="Assignments">
        <ul class="AssignmentsList">
            <h1><% if(lists.length>0){ %></h1>
                <h1>My lists</h1>
                <% lists.forEach(element =>{ %>
                  <h1><%= element.name %></h1>
                  <h1> <%= element._id  %></h1>
                    <a  href="/list<%= element._id  %>" class="deletee" data-myvalue="<%= element._id %>">Delete</a>
                  <% }) %>
                <% } %>
        </ul>
       
    </div>
    <script >
        
        let trashcan = document.querySelector(".Clear");

        trashcan.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            console.log("endpoint");
            let endpoint = `/list/${trashcan.dataset.doc}`;
            fetch(endpoint,{method:'delete'})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => window.location.href= data.redirect)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })


        let owntrash = document.querySelector('.deletee');

        owntrash.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            console.log("fff");
            let endpoint = `/list/${owntrash.dataset.myvalue}`;
            console.log(endpoint);
            fetch(endpoint,{method:'delete'})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>  window.location.href= data.redirect)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })

    </script>

App code 

app.delete('/list',(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
   if(id != undefined)
   {
    console.log("single");
   }
   else{
    console.log("gg");
    myList.find()
    .then(result => result.forEach(element => {
        myList.findByIdAndDelete(element._id)
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }
        ))
        .then(result => res.json({redirect: '/'}))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
   }
})

app.delete('/list/:id',(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    myList.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(resualt => res.json({redirect: '/list'}))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
})



app.get('/list',(req,res)=>{
    myList.find()
    .then(result => res.render('list',{lists:result}))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
})

`
```

after deleting the todo redirect me to the same page (like a refresh)

Answer (score 2):

```
app.delete('/list/:id',(req,res, next)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    myList.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(results => next)
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}, (req, res, next) => {

  //then write the code of what you want to receive after delete

  // to get all the remaining you do this
  myList.find()
  .then(result => res.render('list',{lists:result}))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));
})
```